# UICollectionViewController's layout ownership (self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout vs. self.collectionViewLayout)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionViewController` managing a collection view that uses different layouts for different app states. I'm using `-setCollectionViewLayout:animated:` to transition between the different layouts. I'm having a bad access error, and it would help immensely to know what actually *owns* (e.g. keeps a `strong` reference to) the collection view's current layout.

After calling `-setCollectionViewLayout:animated:`, I've noticed the following (where `self` is the `UICollectionViewController`):

- `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout` returns the new layout.
- `self.collectionViewLayout` still returns the old layout.

This led me to check the [UICollectionView Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UICollectionViewController_clas/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UICollectionViewController/collectionViewLayout), which explains this behavior:

> ## collectionViewLayout
>
> The layout object used to initialize the collection view controller. (read-only)
>
> `@property (nonatomic,readonly) UICollectionViewLayout *collectionViewLayout`
>
> **Discussion**
> This property contains the layout object you passed to the initWithCollectionViewLayout: method. The layout object in this property is not updated to reflect changes to the collection view itself. You can use this property to refer to the layout object you originally configured the collection view to use.

Okay. So `self.collectionViewLayout` is a weak reference (or is it?) to the initial layout and `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout` is a strong reference to the current layout.

To confirm this, I took a dive into the debugger, *but wasn't able to find the actual `UICollectionView`* supposedly owned by the `UICollectionViewController`. Instead, the collection view controller's `_view` variable was an instance of `UICollectionViewControllerWrapperView`. *Whaaaat?*

This whole experience left me with the following questions:

1. Where is the actual `UICollectionView` stored in a `UICollectionViewController`?
2. Does `self.collectionViewLayout` keep a `strong` reference to the initial layout?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where is the actual UICollectionView stored in a UICollectionViewController?

This is really none of your business. I mean, it's interesting that you found a pointer to the collection view, and you could probably find another by searching through the controller's view hierarchy. The important thing is that you should let `UICollectionViewController` worry about the collection view. I know that's not a satisfying answer when you're trying to figure out why your app is crashing, but aside from debugging it's always a good idea to avoid messing with a view controller's views.

> Does self.collectionViewLayout keep a strong reference to the initial layout?

Judging from the documentation, **yes**. Objective-C properties are [strong by default](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW3), and you can see from the property specification that the `collectionViewLayout` property doesn't specify `weak`, so it must be `strong`.

Further evidence comes from the documentation you quoted, which basically says that the property provides a pointer to the layout that you provided at initialization. It doesn't say that the property will return `nil` if you change the layout -- it goes out of the way to say that the property isn't updated and continues to point to the original layout even if you change the layout.

Answer (score 3):

Alright, I've already answered my first question: `UICollectionViewControllerWrapperView` has an ivar called `_subviewCache`, which is a mutable array containing the actual `UICollectionView` at index 0. Weird.

**However, I would still love an answer to my second question.** It seems to me like the collection view controller is *not* keeping a strong reference to the initial layout because its `collectionViewLayout` (initial layout) property is readonly, and I can't find any reference to a collection view layout when inspecting the collection view controller in the variables view of the debugger. Yet, if this is the case, *how is it holding onto the initial layout even after the collection view's strong reference to the initial layout has been replaced with a strong reference to a different layout*?

---

**Update:** It turns out the bad-access crash I was seeing was actually caused by a slightly different issue that has to do with *`UIDynamicAnimator`'s* ownership of the layout. This is almost definitely a bug in Apple's code, and I've filed a radar which you can read here (duplications welcome!):

http://www.openradar.me/15062440

That said, none of this technically addresses my second question. It's no longer relevant to me or to my work, but I'd still welcome and upvote any real answers, even if they'd be purely academic at this point.